# Is java.util.List.removeAll(Collection<?> c) stable?

Tags: java

Is `java.util.List.removeAll(Collection<?> c)` stable?  That is, does `removeAll` preserve the original ordering of the list after the elements in `c` have been removed?

Comment: If it reordered elements, then it would break the general contract of a list.

Comment: I would like to add this comment in my answer by your permission of course! @chrylis

Comment: @Ali Go ahead if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If it reordered elements, then it would break the general contract of a list.

Yes. The removeAll would preserve the original ordering of the list after removing the elements in c.

A very great example i found was here: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-removeall/